# How can I obtain styleable attributes in JAR library? attrs.xml is in main app

Tags: android, xml, jar

I have custom widget as

```
<com.example.MyWidget
        xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        custom:key="242"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

It is declared in jar library.
And I have attrs.xml in main app

```
<declare-styleable name="MyWidget">
    <attr name="key" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

I have to get that value in MyWidget class.

I try to do this in constructor of MyWidget:

```
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.MyWidget);
            try {
                myKey = a.getString(R.styleable.MyWidget_key);
            }
            finally {
                a.recycle();
}
```

but there is NoClassDefFoundException of R$styleable 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `R.styleable.MyWidget` isn't in your jar, so it always will return `NoClassDefFoundException`.

You have to get the attribute:

```
for (int i = 0; i < attrs.getAttributeCount(); i++){
    if (attrs.getAttributeName(i).equals("key")){
        myKey = attrs.getAttributeValue(i));
    }
}
```